# How to divide the columns in a time series by their first value in R?

Tags: matrix, r

I have the code below working. But there must be a better way.

```
file <- "http://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/production/course_1127/datasets/tmp_file.csv"
x <- read.csv(file = file)
ts <- xts(x = x,  order.by = as.Date(rownames(x), "%m/%d/%Y"))
cd=coredata(ts)
for (j in 1:length(names(ts)))  cd[,j]<-cd[,j]/cd[1,j]
for (j in 1:length(names(ts))) ts[,j]<-cd[,j]
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to the code golf and coding challenges stack exchange! While this seems to be a challenge with code you're having, it's not the kind of coding challenge this site is about - the coding challenges here are similar to puzzles or competitions people make for others. You might get more help on Stackoverflow.com, but keep in mind that you need to follow formatting and post content guidelines there.

Comment: While this is likely to be closed with a referral to Stack Overflow, it actually belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: ok, i sit corrected. should i delete the question?